# Ajax tab control wrapping

Tags: ajax, tabs

I have Ajax tab control in  a page with 1000 px width
the tab control contains 19 tabs.
the tabs override the the specified page size.
how can I make the tabs wrap to new line or have next previous buttons.

Answer (score 0):

the following style make the tab wrap to new line

```
    <style type="text/css">

.ajax__tab_default .ajax__tab_header /* this makes the tabs wrap*/ 
{ 
white-space: normal!important; 
} 
</style>
```